# scala sbt common dependencies for multiple external projects with subprojects without plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

Following is my situation:

I want something like:

```
root
  --ProjectSetA
    --SubProjectA1
    --SubProjectA2
    --project/Dependencies
      --DepA1
      --DepA2
    --build.sbt(to aggregate all in SetA)
  --ProjectSetB
    --SubProjectB1
    --SubProjectB2
    --project/Dependencies
      --DepB1
      --DepB2
    --build.sbt(to aggregate all in SetB)
  --build.sbt(aggregate all in root)
```

There are two things I want to do without creating an external sbt plugin:

1)I would like something like in ProjectSetB/build.sbt

```
lazy val newProjectInSetB =
 Project(
  ...,
  dependencies = LocalProject(SubProjectB1) ++ someHow(SubProjectA1)
 )
```

is there a way to implement the function 'someHow()' without implementing a new plugin?

2) I would like to also in ProjectSetB/project/Dependencies

```
private val json4sJacksonLib = "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.4.1"

val newProjectInSetBDep = Seq(json4sJacksonLib, someHow(DepA1))
```

is there a way to implement the function 'someHow()' without implementing a new plugin?

I am open to restructuring/moving dependencies in a common accessible place for all external projects.